# text extraction with pdfminer on mac 12.6.2

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

i'm working on project in pycharm and i would like to use pdfminer to extract text from a pdf. It doesnt work when i try to run the code.
(Python version 3.9.0)
pdfminer.six and pdfminer3k are installed on my mac

thanks in advance!!

```
import re
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages, extract_text

text = extract_text("chapter2.pdf")
print(text)
```

here's the full error message:

```
/Users/bt/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /Users/bt/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bt/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages, extract_text
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfminer'

Process finished with exit code 1
```